# Is there a name for the this kind of recursive formula?

Tags: reference-request, recurrence-relations

$a_{-i}=0$ for all positive i. We have the recurrence

$$
a_n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_ia_{n-m_i}
$$

Where $m_i>0$ for all $i$.

Comment: aren't those the catalan numbers? what's $b_i$?

Comment: $b_i$ and $m_i$ are two infinite sequences. As far as I know, partition numbers can be expressed in this way.

Answer (score 1):

In signal processing, this is a kind of on [IIR filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_impulse_response) or in stochastics this is similar to an [auto regressive process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model#Autoregressive_model).